# What is correct usage of useContext hook to replace Redux/Thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, react-hooks

I am not sure how to use new React feature useContext hook to asynchronously call external resources . 
I want to replace usage of Redux/Thunk with useContext.
What is best practice. I wrote some code to do it.
Can somebody review my code and give me suggestions.

https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-with-side-effect-example-uuyxw

context-auth.js
context provider implementation, reducer,  initialState, mock API call (AuthUser)

login.js
usage of useContext

Code works.
But is it the best practice ?

Comment: I think what you look for is [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I have implemented Auth and Private Routes using Context and React Router.

You can see it in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219398/implementation-of-private-route-with-auth-using-react-router-and-context-api) and [Gist](https://gist.github.com/EduVencovsky/f8f6c275f42f7352571c92a59309e31d).

I also have and example on using `useContext` in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7z905nzx8). It's very basic but I think is more easy to understand.

`useContext` replaces `YourContext.Consumer` and also, you probably wont need to use [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for using the `YourContext.Consumer`.

Now with hooks, you only need `YourContext.Provider`, export `YourContext` and get the value from the context using `let contextValue = useContext(YourContext)`